# How can I add multiple pages and export it in angular2

Tags: angular

Here is my code. But this is not working, please help me any one...

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
@Component({ selector: 'my-app', templateUrl: `page1.html` }) 
@Component({ selector: 'my-app2', templateUrl: `page2.html` }) 
@Component({ selector: 'my-app3', templateUrl: `page3.html` }) 
export class AppComponent{ name = 'Santosh Thakur'; phase = 'learning phase'; btn = 'Submit' } 
export class myApp3 { }
```

Comment: what are you going to export?

Comment: You cannot have multiple `@component` in one component. You may see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678088/multiple-components-in-angular2)

Comment: @Smit you can use multiple `@component` in a single file but thing is you have to create multiple classes too corresponding to components.

Comment: Thanks, Smit it worked :) 
Another question is: How to add event listener with component?
means <div [ngclick]=callFunction()>Call Event</div>
How to wright it?

Comment: Please can any buddy help me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared module for all the components you want to export. Each component should have its own component.ts file and html file. Import all these components in shared module and export them from shared module for use in other modules. Then you can simply import this shared module and have access to all its components. Hope this helps you.